# Using search with Bloodhound

Tags: bloodhound

I am trying to find out how Bloodhound works (without typeahead).

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    local: [{ id: 1, name: 'dog' }, { id: 2, name: 'pig' }],
    identify: function(obj) { return obj.id; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

engine.search('do', function(datums) {
    console.log(datums); // results: []
});
```

In this very basic example, why does my search not return my first item? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, Bloodhound tokenizers work for an array of a basic type. You have "complex" data (an object with 2 properties), so you must tell Bloodhoud what to tokenize using the `obj` tokenizer and passing property names:

```
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("id", "name"),
```